# Is is good to implement redux for single component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question. I am  now implementing redux for my application. In That application, there is a small component which keeps a state of a button color and return a button UI. I want to know that is it good to add this to redux store ? because it is only used for that single component?. Can anyone give me a suggestion ?.

Currently i used redux to keep state between child and parent components.

Comment: even if you are using any state manger such as Redux or Mobx, it is recommended to keep the state of forms, inputs (before submit), buttons, ... locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to handle that state using your local state object instead of Redux. 
Redux is great as it scales with the app and helps in state persistence. Redux for a single component will make it unnecessary complex.

Comment: Yes , That was the my concern. It will add unnecessary complex,  (y)

Answer (score 1):

Nope
Redux is only for the global state and if button color is not related to any other component, it should not be in store
Otherwise after a somewhile you become with a huge unorganizable state that messes everything up